# cURL parameter in objective c or truncated url

Tags: objective-c, curl

I am trying to receive json from a server which is using curl.
The problem is that the &method=somecall will be truncated somehow.
In apple teminal the call is working with '..' around the url, but I can't make it work in Xcode. It results in an invalid url.
Someone mentioned the curl parameter -d to add a method to a call. Is there a way to do it in Objective C?
This url is not working, neither in browser nor in code:

```
http://username:password@someURL/index_api.php?type=json&method=someMethod&id=1
```

OSX Terminal:

```
curl -u username:password 'http://someURL/index_api.php?type=json&method=someMethod&id=1'
```

is working only with the '..'

```
curl -G -u username:password 'http://someURL/index_api.php?type=json&method=someMethod&id=1' -d "type=json" -d "method=omeMethod" -d "id=1"
```

is also working on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to get a response using [BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP) an objective c wrapper for libCurl.

Comment: Even I found a way to make it work I am still interested in the reason why the normal url failed. I appreciate every answere.